# My 2 cats never faught each other. When we moved, fighting was common. How could I resolve this?

Tags: cats, behavior, training, aggression, dominance

## Could I condition them?

I'm gone for 10 hours a day.

There are toys laying around. I play with them once I'm home & through the rest of the day.

Could I effecively condition them to not fight, in a way that doesn't require me and my girlfriend (who is also gone for the same 10 hour timeframe) to be home for it to work?

---

## Details

- One is male (Fearless)
- One is female (Fatty)
- Same age (same litter)
- Both fixed

They lived with 4 other cats. Once we moved, they were the only cats in the house.

Fatty & Fearless now altercate. The reason seemed clear:

> Fatty & Fearless dominated the other 4 cats. Now, with the lack of competition, they're trying to claim dominance over each other.

<sup>If your think the aggression is caused by something else, please mention in your answer</sup>

They can be near each other without fighting, however it's common for them to be chasing each other.

Small scratches have been seen on both cats, including on the nose. Fearless seems to be the one chasing.

However, Fatty seems to be winning the fights, as Fearless tends to have more visible scratches, especially on his nose.

Comment: How long ago was the move? It could be that they still have to claim new territories.

Comment: @Elmy We moved early January, so we've been here for about 9 months.

Comment: Have you tried Feliway? Do you have multiple food, water sources as well as 3 litter boxes? Do they have multiple cat trees around the house, places to hide?